# Journal 3 Filter Issues

Tags: filter, opencart, journal

I have recently updated from Journal 2 to Journal 3. I was using Brainy filter before but due to some compatibility issues with Journal 3, I switched to Journal 3 in-built filter. But the problem is that now when I am adding new products, their attribute values are not picked up by this Journal 3 Filter. Only products with attributes added before are showing up in the results. You can check my site url: https://www.fusion18.com/Salwar-Kameez

For example, the first product is Black colored however once you select "Black" in the filter option to show results of the products in that color, this particular product will not appear in the result. Please suggest as to how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to clear journal 3 cache?

Comment: Yes cleared journal 3 and theme cache also.But still the same issue exist.

Comment: have you disabled Brainy and refreshed the modification after that?

Comment: Yes done that also

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: There was a Journal coding issue which was creating its own database table once new products were added and had to be refreshed by applying changes to the filter module. We have located the issue and fixed it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign filters in category if you want to display new filters.